# Emacs + Cygwin setup under windows !

Tags: emacs

I just downloaded Emacs and Cygwin for Windows(Vista in my case). Have no idea how to set them up.

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks !

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? What exactly do you mean by setting up? Do you already have a .emacs file? are you having trouble configuring the X Window parameters, etc.

Comment: Karra: that may have been slightly optimistic.

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075504/how-to-best-integrate-emacs-and-cygwin

Answer (score 3):

I use these libraries, in this order:

```
(require 'cygwin-mount)
(require 'setup-cygwin)
```

They are both available on EmacsWiki:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/cygwin-mount.el

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/setup-cygwin.el

Comment: `(require 'cygwin-mount)` is not necessary with current version of setup-cygwin.el (it's the first line in setup-cygwin.el)

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Install libraries

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/cygwin-mount.el

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/setup-cygwin.el

Step 2: Install cygwin to `C:\cygwin` (This requirement is hardcoded in setup-cygwin.el, so just do it unless you are willing to modify setup-cygwin.el).

Step 3: Add following code into your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`. Please note the variable `cygwin-mount-cygwin-bin-directory` is not set by default in cygwin-mount.el, I suggest using hard coded path (I mean "c:/cygwin/bin" actually) since the cygwin install path is already hardcoded by setup-cygwin.el.

```
(setq *win32* (eq system-type 'windows-nt) )
;; win32 auto configuration, assuming that cygwin is installed at "c:/cygwin"
(if *win32*
(progn
    (setq cygwin-mount-cygwin-bin-directory "c:/cygwin/bin")
    (require 'setup-cygwin)
    ;(setenv "HOME" "c:/cygwin/home/someuser") ;; better to set HOME env in GUI
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try posting your question on http://superuser.com

But:

- [Installing Emacs on Windows 95/98/2K/NT/ME/XP/Vista/Windows 7](http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/math/alee/emacs/emacs.html)
- [Quick Start Guide for those more experienced with Windows](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-ex-win.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find instructions [here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_mswin.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use cygwin-mount.el to integrate Cygwin with Emacs:

- http://www.khngai.com/emacs/cygwin.php

You might also want to replace the DOS Shell with the Cygwin bash, that's also covered.

Answer (score 0):

There're several way to integrate emacs with cygwin as follows:

1. emacs-nox under cygwin. Not attractive!
2. emacs-X11 under cygwin. An X server is needed like XMing or Cygwin/X. A bit slow and heavy.
3. emacs-w32 under cygwin.
4. emacs under windows. You need some configuration to make emacs recognize the cygwin environment. Difficult for beginners.

I'd recommend using emacs-w32 with cygwin, which uses native Windows GUI so that you don't have to start an xserver just to run emacs and you don't need to write/download any tricky code to make emacs aware of cygwin env as other answers do.

Just install emacs-w32 and run it from mintty and here you go. FYI, if you want to start emacs "independently", write a .bat file with `D:\cygwin\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe --login -i -c /usr/bin/emacs-w32.exe` inside or, as I do, write a .ahk script to start emacs with hotkey `F12`.