# How can I use ediff under Windows + NTEmacs?

Tags: windows, emacs, emacs-ediff

I have Emacs version 23 on Windows and it seem the `ediff` executable is missing?

From where can I download `ediff` for Emacs on Windows?

Comment: M-x ediff, it should be there if you install/build emacs23

Answer (score 17):

If you have git for windows installed, then it is enough to add

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\
```

to your PATH environment variable, because git for windows already ships with a diff executable and installs it in that folder.

Comment: Note that if you do not want to modify your path, you can modify the exec-path in your emacs initialization file to contain this directory as well (exec-path is the PATH list).  Example:  (push "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin" exec-path)

Answer (score 4):

You can download [diffUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm), extract it, add the path to %PATH% and emacs exec-path in your Emacs init file like that.

```
(when (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
  (progn
    (setq diff-path "your-diff-path")
    (setenv "PATH"
            (concat diff-path ";"))
    (setq exec-path
          '(diff-path))))
```

finally, using `M-x diff` to compare what you want.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a Windows-native diff that you're missing. You really want to have access to a suite of additional Unix-like tools when you run NTEmacs.

Cygwin is probably the most common solution. Many people use the GNUWin32 tools instead ("much faster, though less complete, than the Cygwin ones").

See here for more details:
[How to best integrate Emacs and Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075504)

Emacs Wiki: 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CygWin

Be aware that as well as NTEmacs, there is a Cygwin-native Emacs as well. So you can either use NTEmacs with Cygwin providing all the additional tools; or you can ignore NTEmacs entirely, and install Cygwin's Emacs package and just use that. NTEmacs is faster, but Cygwin Emacs integrates better with the rest of Cygwin in a few areas.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `ediff` from emacs, it does indeed look for an executable `diff`. One way to get it is to install cygwin. You don't have to use Emacs from cygwin to use `diff`. Just add `c:\cygwin\bin` (use your cygwin install path) to `%PATH%` and restart emacs.

Now when you run `ediff`, it will find `diff.exe` in your `%PATH%`.

[image: Ediff in emacs on Windows 7]

Comment: Didn't work because it didn't like windows paths. (Might work if I was using Cygwin emacs, but that wasn't really the specified problem.)

Comment: @AdamC: It works outside of cygwin. I attached a screenshot exactly to demonstrate this. What error are you getting? Who did not like what?

Comment: @AdamC I ended up installing http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm and adding the install path to my ``PATH`` env var - that did it. (You'll need to logout/log back in to have everything recognized.)  This is of course old but may be helpful for future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

Ediff uses the `diff` utility so on MS Windows you need to set up `diff` first in order to use Ediff normally. If you already have Git installed then you can use the diff executable packaged with it. Or you can use the single [diffutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm). In order for Emacs to find the executable you can add its path (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`) to the Windows environment variable `PATH` and then restart Emacs. However, if you don't want to restart Emacs all over you can simply add the path to the Emacs variable `exec-path` without changing `PATH`. But this will litter you init file with extra configurations. Another way to add the path to `exec-path` without restarting Emacs or generating extra lines in your init file is like this:

1. Add the executable path to the Windows environment variable `PATH`;
2. Change the Emacs environment variable `PATH` (using `M-x setenv PATH`) to that returned by `echo %PATH%` from CMD;
3. By default `exec-path` is the same as `PATH`. By changing `PATH` manually the original value of `exec-path` also changes. So you can revert its value to the original to synchronize with `PATH`. From the customizing panel (`M-x customize-variable exec-path`) click `Revert...` and choose `2 - Erase Customizations`.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't an executable for `ediff`.

`ediff` is a lisp program that runs within emacs. If you would like to run it from the command line, take a look at [this documentation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EdiffMode#toc2).

Comment: But when using ediff on Windows, Emacs complains about that the diff executable is missing: `apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, diff`

Comment: @ataylor: Sure there is. Ediff mode in emacs runs program `diff`. Look at ediff-diff.el, this line: `(apply 'start-process "Custom Diff" buffer program args))`. Just turn on `debug-on-error` in Windows and run ediff to see for yourself.