# Failure to diff on emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs GNU Emacs 23.3.1.
I don't have admin privileges on my PC hence I just downloaded .zip and use emacs with no problem.

The issue happened when I wanted to compare 2 files : either using Tools->Compare on `M-x diff`.
In both cases when I provided 2 files for comparison it failed with the error:

```
'diff' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Assuming I can't change the path and etc because I don't have privileges how could I fix it?

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423921/how-can-i-use-ediff-under-windows-ntemacs) might be useful.

Comment: Well ... it looks that in this case 'diff' is Unix like command and it's recommended to install Cygwin to have diff. Well ... since I don't have admin privilages I won't be able to do that ...  but anyway ... it's good to know, thanks for info

Comment: susja: Note that there are other options which don't require Cygwin and should only require you to add an executable (to your home directory, perhaps) and tell Emacs where to find it.

Comment: well ... this is interesting .. could you point me to this info? where could I get that executable?

Comment: Try http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... I gave up trying to use Emacs for diff :)
My goal was to be able to diff text and other files ... not necessary using Emacs.
I found out that WinMerge will do the job for me.
Ticket could be closed.